# Four-layer stack-up in PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stack-up

Folks, I am planning to design 4-layer PCB.

I came across the following website which has excellent pointers:

```
http://www.hottconsultants.com/techtips/pcb-stack-up-2.html
```

Here is an excerpt:

> A fourth possibility, not commonly used, but one that can be made to perform very well, is shown in Fig. 4.  This is similar to Fig  2, but with the power plane replaced with a ground plane, and power routed as a trace on the signal layers.
>
> [image: Figure 4 from web site]
>
> This stack-up overcomes the rework problem mentioned before, and still provides for the low ground impedance as a result of two ground planes.  The planes however do not provide any shielding.  This configuration satisfies objectives (1), (2), and (5) but not objectives (3) or (4).
>
> So, as you can see there are more options available, than you might have originally thought, for four layer board stack-up.  It is possible to satisfy four of our five objectives with a four layer PCB.  The configurations of Figures 2, 3b, and 4 all can be made to perform well from an EMC point of view.

My question is why the SIG/GND/PWR/GND variation of Figure 4 in the website is not discussed? Is something fundamentally wrong with the above stack-up?

Comment: it's all about reference planes... your high speed signals only care about the nearest plane is how i think of it

Comment: Nothing really wrong with it (Figure 4).  But having 2 gnd planes right next to each other really doesn't help things at all.  From a power distribution network (PDN) viewpoint, you're better off with a GND/PWR plane configuration, on layers 2 & 3.

Comment: And for high speed signals, a power plane is as good as a GND plane for SI purposes.  They both serve to provide the return path for the high frequency components of signals - minimizing loop area => minimizing path inductance.

Comment: Please just post your links as links. It makes it much easier to find out what you are talking about.

Comment: Isn't *SIG/GND/PWR/GND*, Figure 1 and 2?  Which are discussed.

Comment: Except at very high frequency you can use PWR and GND interchangeably for return current, so putting those two layers together is less common on a 4 layer board.

Comment: ... because sig/gnd/pwr/gnd is an appalling waste of resources. Pwr does not need to be between two Gnds, it doesn't need to be next to a Gnd, it can even be USED as an effective signal ground.

Comment: Neil_UK: "it doesn't need to be next to a Gnd" isn't 100% true, the interplanar capacitance between a GND and PWR plane is an excellent decoupling capacitor.

Comment: @SteveSh: Thanks for the comment! But, I was asking about SIG/GND/PWR/GND stack-up. Why is this stack-up not implemented at all or not common?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: Figure 1 and 2 discuss SIG/GND/PWR/SIG and how the distances between them affect performance.

Comment: @user1850479: Thanks for the input. Nobody has disputed your comment leads me to believe that this would be the case.

Comment: Sorry.  I guess I copied it wrong.  You need at least two layers to route signals. So *SIG/GND/PWR/GND* makes no sense.

Comment: @Dwight Schrute - because GND on the 4th layer really doesn't provide any benefit.  It's almost always better to have at least 2 signal routing layers, except for the simplest of boards.  Like StainlessSteelRat said.

Comment: @SteveSH "a power plane is as good as a GND plane for SI purposes" then why is it commonly believed that SIG-GND-core-GND-SIG is superior to SIG-GND-core-VDD-SIG? I thought that the SIG near VDD would have a large HF current loop due to being physically far away from GND. But you're saying the HF signal can just return through a nearby VDD?

Comment: @Luminaire - Yes, that's what I'm saying.  For a high speed signal, it wants to follow the path of minimum inductance.  That almost always means minimizing the loop area, which may mean using the VDD plane.

Comment: And in your example, where is the VDD layer, or traces?  Without that information, your stackup is not quite complete.

Comment: Finally, you're just considering the return path for signals (I think).  You also need to consider the PDN network and its associated decoupling network (capacitors).

Answer (score 3):

I have heard some issues with sig/gnd/pwr/sig. You have to remember that a signal on layer 4's path to ground is thru the nearest bypass cap. With sig/gnd/gnd/sig-pwr you can shorten the return path by just putting a ground via from layer 2 to 3 right next to your signal via going from 1 to 4.

I guess you have to figure out if your signals are fast enough to really worry about it though. There are millions of 2 layer micocontroller boards out there and the world hasn't ended yet.